# Gimp Creating 3D Round Glossy appearing Button

Tags: gimp

I am trying to create a 3d glossy looking button in Gimp.  How to I create this 3d appearance.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably find some good results from google for this:

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-K8M4-VNms&feature=player_embedded)

[Here's a forum post about it](http://www.cemetech.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=55590)

I'm not sure about all the GIMP terminology, but it can't be too far off from how you would do it in Photoshop (especially if you only need to know the basic *thoughts* behind getting to to look a certain way, rather than a step-by-step how to)

Essentially, to get a 3D look you need depth, which is created by shading. So gradients, shadows, and highlights would all help to achieve this. The glossy look is achieved by additional highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial it will help you to follow...

http://tutoriary.com/graphics/glossy-round-button-with-gimp/